# Create Custom policy in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to validate custom claims which are part of JWT token. Token has custom user claims, application claims and other details.

For user claims, I want to have custom policy/block like

`<validate-logintype> {validation logic in this block} </validation-logintype>`

For application claims, custom policy like

`<request-from> {validation logic} </request-from>`

Include the above blocks in actual API policy

**User API:**

```
    <policy>
       <inbound>
          <validate-logintype>
          <base />
       </inbound>
    </policy>
```

Can someone please help how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-header id="apim-generated-policy" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<yourtenant>/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>{{claim1}}</audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-jwt>
</inbound>
```